# loading multiple json files - 'JSONDecodeError: Expecting value'

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am loading multiple json files:

```
path_to_jsonfiles = '/Users/Dataminingnew/jsonfile/'
for file in os.listdir(path_to_jsonfiles):
     json_data = "%s/%s" % (path_to_jsonfiles, file)
      with open(json_data) as fi:
          rawdata = json.loads(json_data)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Why could that be?

Comment: Do you mean `rawdata = json.load(fi)`?

Comment: want to load all the json in directory one by one

Comment: Yes, `json_data` is the name of your JSON file though, not the file itself. `fi` is the file object that can fetch the actual data.

Comment: Improved code indentation and error message formatting.

Comment: problem is json.load(), How can I solve it?  I changed rawdata = json.load(line.decode("utf-8")) then got error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'

Comment: now I am using this collection_folder = '/Users/Dataminingnew/jsonfile/'
    collection_files = os.listdir(collection_folder)
    for collection_file in collection_files:
         print (collection_file)
    
         with codecs.open(collection_file,'r',encoding='utf-8') as inp_file:
             for line in inp_file:
                 rawdata = json.load(line). but error is AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: If I use rawdata = json.loads(line) then again raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 99: invalid continuation byte if I use                     rawdata =json.load(line)